# CSS : button overlapped by a div,z-index not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]

I have a top bar with a button and a navbar, for z-index reason I can only get the button working but the menu hided under the top bar or I get both but the button not clickable:

PS: I get this problem only on small display with the burger menu,
For the small device, Bootstrap uses this:

```
.navbar-fixed-top, .navbar-fixed-bottom {
position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
}
```

If I override `Z-index:1030;` the bergur menu is hided under my headercss bar.

Here is my almost whole CSS, maybe some parts are not important for my problem:

HTML:

```
<div class="headercss navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="element"> <a class="btn btn-warning" href="www.test.com">Internet &gt;</a></div>
</div>

   <div class="sidebar-nav">
                    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-navbar-collapse">
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse sidebar-navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">test</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
                    </div>
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
.headercss {
    width: 100%;
    height: 62px;
    display:block;
    overflow:auto;
    background-color: #CAD722;
    top: -1px;
    left: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
}

}
.btn {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
 }


/* make sidebar nav vertical */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    font-weight: bold;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {

    .navbar-default{
        width: 200px;;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #e6dfd7;
        z-index: 0;
   }
    .sidebar-nav .navbar .navbar-collapse {
        margin-top: 65px;
        padding: 0;
        max-height: none;
    }
    .sidebar-nav .navbar ul {
        float: none;
        display: block;
    }
    .sidebar-nav .navbar li {
        float: none;
        display: block;
    }
    .sidebar-nav .navbar li a {
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    .sidebar-nav .navbar li a:hover {
        background-color: #CAD722;
    }

}
/*fixing bootstrap*/
.col-sm-10 {
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
    .col-sm-10 {
        width: 85%;
    }

}


    .navbar-default .navbar-collapse,.navbar-default .navbar-form {
    border-color:#CAD722;
}
    .content{
        position: relative;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        margin-top: 11px;
        margin-bottom: 1px;
        margin-left: 5px;
        float: left;
    }

    /*For small display*/
    @media (max-width: 768px) {
        .navbar-default {
            background-color: transparent;
            border-color: transparent;
        }
        .sidebar-nav .navbar li{
            background-color: #CAD722;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide HTML code also

Comment: You need a position before z-index works. for example position:relative;

Comment: @SantoshKhalse, done

Comment: bootstrap sometimes apply z-index: 999; to some elements, so you'll need to aply a higher value. If it's not the problem, try to use bootstrap's standard navbar and then edit it. For more information you must provide more information (as, for example, which breakpoint do you have, the classes that are computed when the issue occurs etc)

Comment: @JoëlBonetRodríguez, you right, I override it but it doesn't work, I get the button working but the menu icon is under the top bar

Comment: you haven't given headercss a width so it takes up the entire width covering the menu icon, try giving it a width:30%; and float:right;

Comment: @Bosc doesn't work

Comment: @user2997418 your navbar-fixed-top is being applied to both navs thats part of the problem you need to change alot of your css around and use different classes, if you can create a jsfiddle it will help.

Comment: @user2997418 I added my link+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you essentially have two full-width navbars sitting on top of each other, with one button in each. Clearly, you'll only be able to click on the top one. One solution is to add `width: 50%;` to `.navbar-default` and `width: 200%;` to `.navbar-collapse` in the small display; This causes the navbar with the menu button to only cover half of the screen, allowing you to click on the Internet button, while the collapsible menu remains full-width.